How did Sirius use Hedwig to send Harry this letter?
In the fifth book, Sirius sent Harry a letter saying "Today, same time, same place."
Hedwig was attacked delivering this letter to Harry.
Harry had sent Hedwig to Sirius earlier in the book once but she had returned with Sirius's reply. So she was at Hogwarts. How did Sirius get to use her to send Harry a letter?

Magic is the answer. They go where they're needed.

The official Wizarding World Fact File site offers a possible explanation:

Wizarding post was delivered using owls. Some wizards and witches preferred to use their own personal owls, but the Owl Post Office was also a large and reliable network for owl delivery that offered speedy and safe communication. Owls were responsible for delivery of packages, newspapers and Hogwarts even had their own Owlery for student use. Due to their intelligence, most owls would be able to find the intended recipient of post even if they were not at their address. Harry's snowy owl, Hedwig, was particularly intuitive, and would sometimes fly to Harry's friends to pick up birthday presents on her way back from delivering something.
(Source: Owl Post on Wizarding World Fact File; emphasis added)

So maybe Hedwig visited Sirius of her own volition and he used the occasion to decide to set up a meeting with Harry.
If the letter was delivered in the morning rather than immediately (I don't have the book handy to check), it's also possible the letter was delivered to Hogwarts via a different owl, and Hedwig was intercepted between the Hogwarts post office and Harry. Update: I reviewed the section and Harry is surprised to see that Hedwig didn't deliver the letter at breakfast, but also seems convinced that she personally brought it from London—so we can at least rule out the possibility that Sirius gave it to a different owl.
